# Saving multiple output in a text file in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

Still trying to learn c++. Our prof wants us to make a program wherein the output of the temperature will be saved in a text file. The variable result is the output that i want to get save. Although the code works and saves the result, the problem is it only saves the first result. I've put a limit, for now i only want to save at least 5 results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   double value, the_result, result;
   int choice;

   ofstream file;
   file.open("output.txt");


   do {

        cout <<"\n\nChoose among the following:"
            "\n1 = Celsius to Fahrenheit"
            "\n2 = Celsius to Kelvin"
            "\n3 = Fahrenheit to Celsius"
            "\n4 = Fahrenheit to Kelvin"
            "\n5 = Kelvin to Celsius"
            "\n6 = Kelvin to Fahrenheit"
            "\n7 = Exit"
            "\n\nChoice:\n";
        cin >> choice;


        switch (choice){

        case 1:
            cout<<"Enter Value"<< endl;
            if (!(cin >> value )){
                cout << "Invalid Input. Please Try Again!!";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(123, '\n');
            }else{
            result = value*9/5+32;
            cout <<"The result is ~"<< result << "\370";
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            cout<<"Enter Value"<< endl;
            if (!(cin >> value )){
                cout << "Invalid Input. Please Try Again!!";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(123, '\n');
            }else{
            result = value+273.15;
            cout <<"The result is ~"<< result << "K";
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            cout<<"Enter Value"<< endl;
            if (!(cin >> value )){
                cout << "Invalid Input. Please Try Again!!";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(123, '\n');
            }else{
            the_result = value-32;
            result = the_result*5/9;
            cout <<"The result is ~"<< result << "\370" << "F";
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            cout<<"Enter Value"<< endl;
            if (!(cin >> value )){
                cout << "Invalid Input. Please Try Again!!";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(123, '\n');
            }else{
            the_result = value + 459.67;
            result = the_result*5/9;
            cout <<"The result is ~"<< result << "K";
            }
            break;

        case 5:
            cout<<"Enter Value"<< endl;
            if (!(cin >> value )){
                cout << "Invalid Input. Please Try Again!!";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(123, '\n');
            }else{
            result = value - 273.15;
            cout <<"The result is ~"<< result << "\370";
            }
            break;

        case 6:
            cout<<"Enter Value"<< endl;
            if (!(cin >> value )){
                cout << "Invalid Input. Please Try Again!!";
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(123, '\n');
            }else{
            result = value*9/5-459.67;
            cout <<"The result is ~"<< result << "\370" << "F";
            }
            break;

        case 7:
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            break;


        }


        for (double i=0; i<5; i++){
            file << result<< endl;
        }
        file.close();
   }
   while (choice !=7);
}
```

Comment: You close the file inside the `do while` loop, that should be done outside (or let the implicit close done by the constructor do the work, as you don't do any error checking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on AProgrammer's comment - The problem is after the first iteration you are trying to write to a file that you have already closed and not reopened. So as suggested you should move the `file.close()` outside of the do while loop